# Will leaving the US with an overstay affect UK transit or transit visa?

Tags: air-travel, uk, transit-visas

I have overstayed in the US for three years. Now I am returning to my home country and, while booking the ticket from the US, note that the flight has a stopover at London Heathrow of 1 hour 40 minutes. Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a bit clearer. It is correct that you're in the US now and will travelling from there via London? And what is your nationality, please?

Comment: indian and i had overstayed in my tourist visa.